# dynamic distribution group with enabled accounts only

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

Is it possible to add a condition to dynamic distribution group in Exchange 2007 that will filter for enabled accounts only?

When a staff member leaves we have to keep their account in the system for a certain amount of time because of data protection or something, but eventually the mailboxes get full and start rejecting mail, which is annoying for the senders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you disable the user account, be sure to disable the corresponding mailbox as well.

You can then filter on the `IsMailboxEnabled` property in your distribution groups:

```
New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name AllUsersGroup -OrganizationalUnit domain.tld/Users -RecipientFilter {((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and -not(IsMailboxEnabled -eq $false))}
```

Comment: That's handy but is it possible to do it based on whether the AD account is enabled/disabled?

Comment: @toryan Not according to the [filterable properties documentation for Exchange 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430771(v=exchg.80).aspx)